# Splitting an iTunes Library

Tags: itunes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iTunes videos on a different harddrive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11552/itunes-videos-on-a-different-harddrive)

I have read several articles online about the most efficient means of splitting an iTunes library across multiple drives, unfortunately none seems efficient and some that I have tried do not work as advertised.  So I thought I would throw this out to this community to see if anyone has a more workable solution... I am running the very latest version of iTunes 10.5.2 on the very latest version of OSX 10.7.2 on a Mac mini that has two 750GB drives.  I need to split Movies from Music/Audiobooks due to the size of my library.  I copied all movies to the second internal drive manually, and deleted them from my library then I unchecked the preference options to keep the folder organized and to copy items when adding to the library but each time I try to drag the Movies back into iTunes it seems to be copying them onto  the primary drive as if I hadn't unchecked the options.  What the .... ?  Anyway can someone tell me what the secret incantation is to do this split?  This is RIDICULOUS and I know this is not the first time someone has run into a disk size limitation for an iTunes library. Apple really needs to address this in some straightforward manner!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This is bordering on being a rant. Please do not post rants on this site, but focus on what you want to achieve. In any case, your question has already been addressed here. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have all my movies on an external hard-drive as well. There's an easy fix:

Delete all movies from the library, but keep the option for automatic organization checked, so iTunes manages your music etc.

Now drag all your movies from the second drive to the iTunes sidebar over the Movies folder. Press and hold the 'alt'-key and release the mouse. This created links to all your movies. You need to organize the Movies-folder by hand, but that's not that bad.

See also this question: [iTunes videos on a different harddrive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11552/itunes-videos-on-a-different-harddrive)